# Hibernate search multiple entities

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Is it possible to search multiple entities for the same keyword, filtering each type with a specific filter and getting them in a single list?

For example having the entities, breeder and animal and searching their data for the terms "Boston Terrier". After that the breeders are filtered for location and animals for species and a single list is returned containing both Animals and Breeders.

This list can then be trimmed to enable pagination of the results in the front end of a web-application:

```
        // FullTextQuery ftq = .... definiing and filtering the query

        int numResults = ftq.getResultSize();
        ftq.setFirstResult((pageNum-1)*numPerPage);
        ftq.setMaxResults(numPerPage);

        List<Object> results = ftq.getResultList();
```

Comment: When you say you want to return "both Animals and Breeders", do you mean you want something like: <Breeder1: Animal1, Animal2>, <Breeder2: Animal3>, <Breeder4: Animal5>, with both breeders and animals matching all of the search criteria, or do you not care at all about the relationship between animals and breeders (e.g. a dog with a species matching your search criteria but bred by a breeder outside of your location criteria would match)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. At this stage the relation between breeders and animals is not important. All I want is to show results of breeders and animals for a certain keyword and criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the relation between breeders and animals, and just want to search for animals OR breeders: yes, you can.

But there are some conditions:

- the fields you will apply your "Boston Terrier" term filter on must be configured the *exact same way* in the `Animal` class and the `Breeder` class: same analyzer in particular. Otherwise, your search results will probably be inconsistent. The fields do not have to exist in both indexes: filtering on an "animalName" and "breederName" fields should work fine.
- the location field you want to use to filter the breeders by location **must not exist** in the `Animal` class. Otherwise, the animals will be filtered by location too.
- the species field you want to use to filter the animals by species **must not exist** in the `Breeder` class. Otherwise, the breeders will be filtered by species too.

If the answer to all three items above is "yep, I'm good", then you can do the following.

---

EDIT: Nowadays I would strongly recommend upgrading to Hibernate Search 6.0 or above, which makes searching multiple indexes in the same query much easier.

In fact, you don't have to do anything specific, except listing the targeted types.

The snippet from my original answer, converted to Hibernate Search 6, would look something like this:

```java
EntityManager em = ...;
List<Object> hits = Search.session(em)
        .search(Arrays.asList(Animal.class, Breeder.class))
        .where(f -> f.bool()
                .must(f.simpleQueryString()
                        .fields("animalName",
                                "breeder.company.legalName",
                                "breeder.firstName",
                                "breeder.lastName")
                        .matching("Boston Terrier")
                        .defaultOperator(BooleanOperator.AND))
                .must(f.bool()
                        .should(f.spatial().within()
                               .field("breederLocation")
                               .circle(42.0, 42.0,
                                        50, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS))
                        .should(f.match()
                               .field("species")
                               .matching(<some species>)))
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

---

ORIGINAL SOLUTION, for Hibernate Search 5:

- create a `QueryBuilder` for `Animal`, say `animalQueryBuilder`
- create another `QueryBuilder` for `Breeder`, say `breederQueryBuilder`
- use the `animalQueryBuilder` for the species filter.
- use the `breederQueryBuilder` for the location filter
- use one builder or the other (it shouldn't matter) for the term filter

Then, when creating the query, pass both the Animal class and the Breeder class to the `createFullTextQuery` method.

The query should return both animals and breeders.

Something like that:

```
QueryBuilder animalQueryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( Animal.class ).get();
QueryBuilder breederQueryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( Breeder.class ).get();

Query locationQuery = breederQueryBuilder.spatial()
    .onField( "breederLocation" )
    .within( 10.0, DistanceUnit.KM )
    .ofLatitude( 42.0 ).andLongitude( 42.0 )
    .createQuery();
Query speciesQuery = animalQueryBuilder.keyword()
    .onField( "species" )
    .matching( <some species> );
Query termsQuery = animalQueryBuilder.simpleQueryString()
    .onFields(
        "animalName", "breeder.company.legalName",
        "breeder.firstName", "breeder.lastName"
    )
    .withAndAsDefaultOperator()
    .matching( "Boston Terrier" );

Query booleanQuery = animalQueryBuilder.bool()
    .must( termsQuery )
    .must( animalQueryBuilder.bool()
        .should( locationQuery )
        .should( speciesQuery )
        .createQuery()
    )
    .createQuery();

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery( booleanQuery, Animal.class, Breeder.class );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm

Comment: Glad it helped. Regarding your edit attempt, know that using `.should( breederQueryBuilder.all().createQuery() ).should( speciesQuery )` will return *all* animals regardless of their species, and will simply put animals with a matching species higher up in the results. I'd suggest using something like `.should( breederQueryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField( "<some field found in all breeders and only breeders>" ).matching( "*" ).createQuery() ).should( speciesQuery )` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't the BreederQueryBuilder.all() apply to only the Breeder class?  If that's not the case then your proposed method makes perfect sense.

Comment: It wouldn't apply only to the Breeder class, not really. It would just add a query matching everything, regardless of the entity type.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks :) Your help is much appreciated.